# How to avoid a web.xml error page in a specific page

Tags: jsf, web.xml, jsf-1.2

I have the following `error-pages` in my `web.xml` file:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/pages/inactivity.jsf</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/pages/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

The problem is the following:

Sometimes, I get the `ViewExpiredException`, and it goes to the `inactivity` page, but, seems like some `.xhtml` file tries to use something that's not in session anymore, then I generally got a `NullPointerException`. But, the second error is a child of the first one, so, my first error handle should be enought.

I was wondering if is there a way to made `error-page` for a specific `exception-type` not be showned in some specific page (in inactivity, in my case).

Is there a way to do this?

BTW: I'm using JSF 1.2.

---

**EDIT**

[Complete Exception](https://gist.github.com/2997436).

Also, I just realized that it dont happens in Firefox, just chrome. Dont test in IE because I dont have it :)

Comment: I don't understand the concrete problem. How exactly is the NPE related to the `ViewExpiredException`? What exactly happens instead? What exactly did you expect? What exactly do you mean with "second error is a child of the first one"? Isn't that NPE just a bug in your own code?

Comment: Actually, with `ViewExpiredException` I don't remember, and is very rare. It occurs most if I leave the `session-timeout` = 1 in `web.xml`. Then, when I try to use a `ManagedBean`, I got a `ManagedBeanCreationException`, that should redirect to inactivity too (mapped in web.xml). In this case, when the `ManagedBeanCreationException` occurs, the inactivy page is show, but, because the managed bean is null (due to the fail to initialize it), I also got Faces Exceptions in my xhtml files, and then it goes to the error page.

Comment: Well... A concrete stacktrace would be very helpful in understanding your concrete problem. Your last comment gives still the impression that you've just a bug in your own code.

Comment: Well, you've just a bug at line 382 of `ManagedUserioLogado`, in the `inicializarUsario()` method. Fix it and then we can talk further.

Comment: Yeah, I see that... but I don't understand why it occurs, because if it was not possible to initialize ManagedUsuarioLogado class, how can it fall in a method inside the class?

Comment: BTW: after avoiding the nullpointer, I can get it working... but, is strange that it doesnt happen in chrome. Thanks, anyway.